# How I can use IText in Java11

Tags: java, itext, java-platform-module-system

I have this Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

but my mvn clean install say: com.itextpdf.text is not visible. How I can add iText to my Jigsaw package-info.java?

Comment: Have you tried iText 7? That should work with newer Java versions. iText 5 is End Of Life and was built for Java 5 and won't receive any updates except security fixes.

Comment: Thank you. Now I use iText 7 but the build return a error "provider class org.apache.bsf.bsfmanager not in module"